# Node js won't subscribe to a redis channel with another name

Tags: node.js, redis, socket.io

I'm having trouble getting node js to recognize any other channel but "message". The channel name "message" is recognized, but when I change the channel name to any other name node doesn't subscribe and respond to the channel name.

**Example:**

```
var sub = redis.createClient();

sub.subscribe('message');

sub.on('message', function (channel, data) {

   data = JSON.parse(data);
   console.log('chat', channel, data);

});

/*
* Server
*/

// Start listening for incoming client connections
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

   console.log('NEW CLIENT CONNECTED');


   socket.on('disconnect', function () {
      console.log('DISCONNECT');
    //I've tried using unsubscribe to message to fix problem
    //sub.unsubscribe('message');
   });

});
```

**The above code works and outputs onto the console:**

```
chat message { room: 1 }
DISCONNECT
NEW CLIENT CONNECTED
```

**The below code does not log the channels subscription log:**

> NEW CLIENT CONNECTED
>   DISCONNECT

```
var sub = redis.createClient();

sub.subscribe('chat');

//Does not output anything to console
sub.on('chat', function (channel, data) {

   data = JSON.parse(data);
   console.log('chat', channel, data);

});

/*
* Server
*/

// Start listening for incoming client connections
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

   console.log('NEW CLIENT CONNECTED');


   socket.on('disconnect', function () {
      console.log('DISCONNECT');
    //I've tried using unsubscribe to message to fix problem
    //sub.unsubscribe('message');
   });

});
```

**redis-cli MONITOR:**

```
1485546938.714486 [0 127.0.0.1:49881] "info"
1485546938.717446 [0 127.0.0.1:49881] "subscribe" "message"
1485546945.902959 [0 127.0.0.1:49897] "SELECT" "0"
1485546945.903406 [0 127.0.0.1:49897] "PUBLISH" "message" "{\"room\":1}"

1485546868.850918 [0 127.0.0.1:49857] "info"
1485546868.853824 [0 127.0.0.1:49857] "subscribe" "chat"
1485546875.332391 [0 127.0.0.1:49873] "SELECT" "0"
1485546875.332861 [0 127.0.0.1:49873] "PUBLISH" "chat" "{\"room\":1}"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameter is always 'message' regardless of channel name. Its like this:

```
sub.on("message", function (channel, message) {
  console.log("sub channel " + channel + ": " + message);
});
```

Comment: If you could provide me documentation on the method 'on' i'd be very thankful.

Comment: @user3325126 I would read up on EventEmitter: https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_emitter_on_eventname_listener